# Linq query where clause in sub list

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to get instances with only certain sub instances.

Having two classes:

```
class Center
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Sub> SubList { get; set; }
}

class Sub
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Filled with data:

```
void Main()
{
   var list = new List<Center>();
   list.Add(new Center
   {
      Id = 1,
      Name = "Main1",
      SubList = new List<Sub>
      {
        new Sub { Code = "A", EndDate = null },
        new Sub { Code = "B", EndDate = new DateTime(2021,2,1) },
        new Sub { Code = "C", EndDate = new DateTime(2021,2,1) },
      }
   });

   list.Add(new Center
   {
      Id = 2,
      Name = "Main2",
      SubList = new List<Sub>
      {
        new Sub { Code = "X", EndDate = null },
        new Sub { Code = "Y", EndDate = null },
        new Sub { Code = "Z", EndDate = null },
      }
   });
}
```

I want to get a list of 'Centers' with only the SubList where enddate is null or in the future.
So the result should be (in json):

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Main1",
    "SubList": [
      {
        "Code": "A",
        "EndDate": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Main2",
    "SubList": [
      {
        "Code": "X",
        "EndDate": null
      },
      {
        "Code": "Y",
        "EndDate": null
      },
      {
        "Code": "Z",
        "EndDate": "2021-06-04T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Came up with:

```
   var l = list.Select(
      x =>
      new
      {
         x.Id,
         x.Name,
         SubList = x.SubList.Where(s => s.EndDate == null || s.EndDate > DateTime.Now)
      });
```

This is the result I want, but can this be done more easily? Something like:

```
var l = list.Where(x => x.SubList.Where(s => s.EndDate == null || s.EndDate > DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add a copy method in your `Center` and `Sub` class:

```
class Center
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Sub> SubList { get; set; }

   public Center Copy()
   {
     return new Center { Id = this.Id, Name = this.Name, SubList = this.SubList.Select(x => x.Copy()).ToList() };
   }
}

class Sub
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

   public Sub Copy()
   {
      return new Sub { Code = this.Code, EndDate = this.EndDate };
   }
}
```

Then you can first copy your List:

```
var l = list.Select(center => center.Copy()).ToList();
```

It's not LINQ, but you can modify this copy with `ForEach` of `List<T>`:

```
l.ForEach(x => x.SubList = x.SubList.Where(s => s.EndDate == null || s.EndDate > DateTime.Now).ToList());
```

If it's ok to modify the original list, you don't need the copy stuff. Just use:

```
list.ForEach(x => x.SubList = x.SubList.Where(s => s.EndDate == null || s.EndDate > DateTime.Now).ToList());
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why do you need `Copy`?